# Returning multiple results from mysql to separate jQuery modals

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, modal-dialog

I am creating a PHP search page that searches a MySQL database and returns results into separate jQuery modals.

**Goal**: When a user searches a term, the results found for `ClassName` are displayed from the database via separate links (these links being scripted to open jQuery modals) and once a link is clicked the modal opens displaying the rest of the information related to that `ClassName` in said database.

**What Is Working**: The different `ClassName`(s) are displayed properly as separate links.

**What Is Not Working**: No matter what `ClassName` link you click on, once the modal opens, it only displays the information relating to the very first `ClassName` result in the database.

Any help correcting this error is greatly appreciated.

The only rows in the database I am using for results are: `ClassName`, `ClassInformation`, and `imagePath`.

PHP Select Statement:

```
<?php 
$raw_results = mysql_query(
   "SELECT * FROM classes
    WHERE (`ClassName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR 
   (`ClassInformation` LIKE '%".$query."%')"
) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Link:

```
echo "<a href=".$results['ClassName']
   . " data-reveal-id='myModal'><h2>"
   . $results['ClassName']
   . "</h2></a>";
```

Modal:

```
echo "<div id='myModal' class='reveal-modal' 
    style='background-image: url(ResultBackground.png);
    border: 1px solid black;'><h2>".$results['ClassName']."</h2>
    <div id='image'>".$results['imagePath']."</div></br >
    <h3>".$results['ClassInformation']."</h3>
    <a class='close-reveal-modal'>&#215;</a></div>";
```

I apologize for the code not formatting correctly I don't really understand how to use the code blocks on this site yet. But thank you for any and all help offered.

A similar question was asked by someone 2 months ago here [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162694/passing-mysql-data-to-modal-form-via-php?rq=1) but the way his code was written threw me off completely as I'm new to PHP and only know the messy way I've taught myself from online tutorials. I attempted to format the code similar to the way suggested by the person who answered the linked question but I just keep breaking my code.

Comment: Note: I understand that the mysql_* is deprecated and I plan to modify it to fit PDO standards as soon as I get it functioning the way I want.

Comment: `$sql="SELECT * FROM classes WHERE (ClassName LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (ClassInformation LIKE '%".$query."%')";`
If you `echo $sql;` what does it return?

Comment: Ultimater to answer your question echoing $sql returned nothing and caused a scream suppression because $sql isnt identified in my code. But thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $i=0;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
    echo "<a href=".$results['ClassName']. " data-reveal-id='myModal_".$i."'><h2>".$results['ClassName']. "</h2></a>";
    echo "<div id='myModal_".$i."' class='reveal-modal'>......restcode";
    $i++;
    }
```

You have to use unique ids fro each link .here you have used same data-reveal-id="myModal" for every link,and every modal div has same id "myModal". So when you click on any link,it checks for first element  with id 'myModal' and displays it .
  Use different data-reveal-ids for each link and give the same id to the corresponding modal divs

Comment: Bhadra you are amazing! It worked perfectly. I had no clue a count could fix the issue so easily. You sir are a godsend. Thank you so much!