# Bootstrap modal issue with ckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, ckeditor

This is some how related to [Passing MySQL data to Modal Form via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162694/passing-mysql-data-to-modal-form-via-php) because I am using method mentioned in that article to edit records.

But now I have quite surprising issue in it. I am using ckeditor to edit product details but when I use it in there, it shows only in the first record. In next records, simple textarea comes up.

Here is code which comes in while loop.

```
  <div class="modal" id="modaledit<?=$id; ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Product</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="formleft">Name:</div>
          <div class="formright"><input type="text" name="prod_name" value="<?=$r["prod_name"]; ?>" /></div>

          <div class="formleft">Details:</div>
          <div class="formright">
            <textarea name="prod_details" cols="40" rows="10" id="editor1"><?=$r["prod_details"]; ?></textarea>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
                {
                    filebrowserBrowseUrl :'js/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Connector=<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
                    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'js/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
                    filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl :'js/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Flash&Connector=<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
                    filebrowserUploadUrl  :'<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=File',
                    filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Image',
                    filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : '<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Flash'
                });

            //]]>
            </script>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" style="color:#ffffff;" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$('#formprod').submit();">Submit</a>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

It has become a headache for me because first I tried with external page modal, but there ckeditor does not show up for any record. And here it does show up, but only for first record. weird!!!

**EDIT**

Another thing I noticed, actually ckeditor is showing in modal for only one time. Basically, I am using two modals on same page, one for add new record and one for edit. And because edit modal is inside while loop of showing all products, so it comes earlier on page. And then, ckeditor shows up only for first record edit. Now I notice that ckeditor is not showing up in add new record modal as well (where it was working perfectly before I wrote edit modal code).

Comment: Maybe isn't useful... have you tried launching the "replace" of CkEditor on modal_shown event? Bootstrap give you an event to launch code, maybe the ckeditor go down when the modal is hidden. (hide or hidden modal action too)

Comment: Thanks Goikiu, actually I am quite new to this bootstrap thing, could you please show with code?

Comment: Another thing I noticed, actually ckeditor is showing in modal for only one time. Basically, I am using two modals on same page, one for add new record and one for edit. And because edit modal is inside while loop of showing all products, so it comes earlier on page. And then, ckeditor shows up only for first record edit. Now I notice that ckeditor is not showing up in add new record modal as well (where it was working perfectly before I wrote edit modal code). So, definitely your solution will work. I will be thankful if you please can write a demo code according to my need, thanks.

Comment: i've give you an answer, please, refresh the page =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what shows up in the error console:

```
Uncaught [CKEDITOR.editor] The instance "editor1" already exists.
```

If you plan to use more than one instance of CKEditor on your page do the following:

A) Assign different ID to each textarea element you plan to replace. Something like this should do the trick in your case:

```
<textarea name="prod_details" cols="40" rows="10" id="editor<?=$id; ?>">
```

and later:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor<?=$id; ?>',
```

OR

B) Or call something like [CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy();](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-destroy) whenever you close the modal dialog window

---

Keep in mind that you have different errors on this sample page, HTTP 404 requests and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

which may result in CKEditor not loading etc.

Comment: Great man, thanks so, so, so much. You saved my head from being blown up. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BootStrap than you got Jquery, that said you can add this kind of code (Example)

```
<script>
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
 //<![CDATA[
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
            {
                filebrowserBrowseUrl :'js/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Connector=<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'js/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
                filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl :'js/ckeditor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html?Type=Flash&Connector=<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/connector.php',
                filebrowserUploadUrl  :'<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=File',
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl : '<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Image',
                filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : '<?php echo $url;?>js/ckeditor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php?Type=Flash'
            });

        //]]>
})
</script>
```

Please note that this example code is binded to the modal class, if you are using modal only for this you can give a try. However, you do not need to have 100 Modal if you've got 100 rows, you can simply use 1 modal and change the contents with Javascript/Jquery when needed.

EDIT: Added the  part.

Comment: Thanks, and yes i tried to have one modal for edit but then problem arose in passing product ID to edit modal where I can query mysql for that ID to get values from table, so I had to choose this way. Actually I am a network person trying hands on web applications, so I am like a starter in javascript. That's why I don't even know how to use your above proposed code. :(( Please pardon me this.

Comment: Ok, comment the code inside the edit modal and put this code into <script></script> right after the start tag <body> and see if anything different happen on editing a lot of rows.

Comment: I did that, put your code inside script tag after <body> and called both textareas of ADD and EDIT with <textarea id="editor1">. Now ckeditor shows no where.

Comment: change my scrypt with this and retry: $(document).bind('afterClose.facebox', function() {
 if (CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'])
  CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].destroy(true);
});  BUT recopy the page as it was before make a comment of CDATA inside the modal

Comment: No sir, same old result i.e showing on only first record, Kindly check here http://xvision.ae/check.html . I copied source from localhost to that link.