# How to display data from mysql in a bootstrap modal in codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap-3, phpmyadmin, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to fetch the product details from the database and display in a bootstrap modal. Please can someone help me.

welcome_message.php view

```
<div class="mix category-1 col-md-3" data-myorder="2">
            <div class="product-item">
                    <div class="product-block">
                        <div class="product-block-inner">
                            <div class="h3">
                                W210 Cashew
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-image">
                                <img src="assets/images/Products/Whole Cashew/
                                W210.jpe" class="img-responsive"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info-inquiry">
                                <span class="info-button">

                                    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="INFO" 
                                CLASS="INFO-BUTTON" VALUE="INFO / INQUIRY"
                                     TITLE="INFO/INQUIRY" 
                                     data-toggle="modal" 
                                     data-target="#exampleModal"
                                      data-whatever="W180" />
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Modal in welcome_message.php

```
<div id="exampleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"                    
                 aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-content">

            </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                    data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

        $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#exampleModal' ,function(event){

             var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
             var id = button.data('whatever')
             var modal = $(this)
        $.ajax({
            url:'<?php echo base_url();?>/Welcome/ProductbyId',
            data: {id:'id'},
            dataType:'json',
            type: "POST",

            success: function(data){
                var result = jQuery.parse(data);
                alert(result);
                $('.modal-body','#exampleModal')[0].html(result);*/
                }

        }); 
        });
        </script>
```

Welcome.php Controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('productdetail');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('layout/header');
        $this->load->view('viewmenu.php');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }

    public function ProductbyId() {

                log_message('debug','Function called');

        /*$productId = $_POST['id'];*/
        $productId = "$_POST[id]";
        $productId = 'W180';
    log_message('info',$productId);

        $data["results"] = $this->productdetail->ProductdetailbyId($productId);
        echo json_encode($data["results"]);
    }
```

model Productdetail.php

```
<?php
    class productdetail extends CI_Model {
        function ProductdetailbyId($id){
            $condition = "Id =" . "'" . $id . "'";
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('productlist');
            $this->db->where($condition);
            $this->db->limit(1);
            $query = $this->db->get();

             if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
        }
}
?>
```

Please can anyone explain, how to display data from ajax call on success in bootstrap modal?

Comment: I am a newbie. Please can you tell me how to display data via ajax to bootstrap modal or please can you provide any tutorial link

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162694/passing-mysql-data-to-modal-form-via-php